# Queries on permutation 1...N

Tags: algorithm

So we are given a permutation of the numers {1... N}.
We are given an integer k and then k queries of this type:

q(x,y,l,r) - count numbers between position X and Y in the permutation, which are >=l and <=r.

For example: 
N - 7: **(1 6 3 5 7 4 2)**

**q(1,4,2,7)** -> 3 numbers ( **6, 3 and 5** , since 2<=6<=7 , 2<=3<=7 and  2<=5<=7)

So my attempt was to store the permutation and and position array (too have fast acces to the position of each number)
Then i check which interval is smaller [x,y] or [l,r] and iterate through the smaller.
The answers i get are correct, but i get 0 points, since my solution it's too slow.
Any tips how to make this queries as fast as possible for big N?

```cpp
        #include <iostream>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int q;
    cin >> q;
    int* perm = new int[n+1];

    int* pos = new int[n+1];
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        int num;
        cin >> num;
        perm[i] = num;
        pos[num] = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        int x, y, l, r;
        cin >> x >>y>> l>> r;
        int count = 0;
        if (y - x < r - l)
        {
            for (int i = x; i <= y; i++)
            {
                if (perm[i] >= l && perm[i] <= r)
                    count++;
            }
            cout << count << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = l; i <= r; i++)
            {
                if (pos[i] >= x && pos[i] <= y)
                    count++;
            }
            cout << count << endl;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Show some code. So far it is not known how the permutation itself gets to the algorithm (it is not part of `q(1,4,2,7)`), and even the programming language remains unknown. Looping over `[l,r]` does not seem to be a good idea, by the way.

Comment: Here is the code. I don't see any point in giving it, since its obviously too slow.

Comment: You need to "execute k queries" is very unclear. Can you edit to clarify? Perhaps retyping the question as it is given in the task would be the best.

Comment: It's better now ?

Comment: Yes. So k queries are given in the single run of the program? I don't see "k" in your code. Also is only one permutation given in the single run of the program?

Comment: in the code the queries count is not k, its q.

Comment: At least now I understand what you meant on looping over the shorter interval, and that part is fine, just apparently not enough. You might gain a minor speedup in the loops by using direct pointers and prefix increments, like `int *stop=perm+y+1;for(int *curr=perm+x;curr!=stop;++curr)if(*curr>=l && *curr<=r)++count;`, but I have a feeling that you are supposed to use some more specialized helper structure, not just a list.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions on how to improve already working code should be on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Iguananaut if you want to get rid of it, I think it rather belongs to CS and needs some particular "*idea*".

Comment: I mean stackoverflow has become a disaster, not one question is on topic. Reminds me of why I stopped using it.